# Upload and attach a file to an account or opportunity

Tags: api, opportunity, account, upload

So I was wondering how I can attach a file to an account. Basically what we do is sell a product online that requires an agreement. When they buy the product, we generate a pdf of the agreement and mail it to them. What I would like to do is upload the pdf agreement and attach it to the corresponding opportunity or account. I am pretty sure this can be accomplished, but I don't see much documentation on it. I am using php and the API to create everything. Any one have any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just create an [Attachment](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_attachment.htm) on the Account. It should work the same way as creating an object in Salesforce.

Some important considerations:

- The API sends and receives the binary file attachment data encoded as a base64Binary data type. Prior to creating a record, client applications must encode the binary attachment data as base64. Upon receiving a response, client applications must decode the base64 data to binary (this conversion is usually handled for you by the SOAP client).
- The create call restricts these files to a maximum size of 5 MB. For a file attached to a Solution, the limit is 1.5MB. The maximum email attachment size is 3 MB.

Comment: This worked perfectly for what I was trying to achieve. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend using chatter files related to the record rather than attachments as chatter files have a number of [features](http://blogs.salesforce.com/community/2012/04/chatter-files-a-better-option-for-attaching-files-to-records.html) that attachments lack.

To upload a file and relate it to a record you use a [feeditem](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm) with the following required fields.

```
ContentData: base64 encoded file
ContentFileName: file name
ParentId: account/opportunity ID
Type: 'ContentPost'
```

Answer (score 5):

I would like to recommend ready to use Salesforce Appexchange Native App **Cloud Drop** in order to store any number and size of files that can be associated with any salesforce object. Cloud Drop is one of a smart and excellent native app available which integrated Salesforce with Rackspace. Please check the following link for more information:

**https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003IzEDEA0**

Thanks
Anchal Garg

Comment: Can you explain the benefits of this over the default attachements, and how this can be API integrated ? Else this is pretty much advertising which usually gets removed.

Comment: Samuel ,As you know their are several limitation of salesforce default attachment : 1. Max size of attachment that can be associated with a particular sfdc record is 5 MB 2. Also the size of the uploaded file count against the salesforce file storage space (which seems to be costly if user needs to attach large no. of file.) So, A good solution for this issue would be use third party api(Rest) for saving file content there and making a record for that in salesforce for fetching the content of file .CloudDrop app is using same logic for uploading and downloading of the file to Rackspace server.